# Why does AWS Health check take so long to change from Healthy to Unhealthy and Vica Versa

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have setup some string matching based health checks in Amazon Route 53.

I have them with 10 second ( Fast ) request intervals and changed the Failure threshold to 1.

However it seems to be taking up to 1 minute for the dashboard to display the health check as healthy. If it is polling so often and the threshold is 1, shouldn't it switch over quicker?

Many thanks,

Comment: Have you tested to verify that the issue isn't limited to the display?  It could be that resource records depending on the check react faster than the console would suggest.

Comment: Sounds like a propagation delay in reporting the health to CloudWatch.  Have you tried creating a test record and querying Route 53 directly?